BlockUI loading panel is working in environment but hide in other one
I am using Primefaces 13 with a combination of JBoss 7.4 and Java 11.
I used a blockUi to block the entire form until a bulk transaction is done (may take more than 10 Mins).
The code was working fine with Primefaces 6, JBoss 7.2, and Java 8, in all environments. But after upgrading to the above-mentioned versions, the block is working in the DEV environment until the end of the transaction, but in the Production environment, the loading panel disappears after some minutes. However, the process is not finished and is running in the background.
The below one is invoking the blockUI:
onstart="PF('blockUi2').show()" oncomplete="PF('blockUi2').hide()"

The below code is to block the whole form:
<p:blockUI block="data" id="mqp-blockui"   widgetVar="blockUi2" ><img style="height:8em;background-color:transparent !important;" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/themes/default/pics/loading.gif</p:blockUI>


Please add a [mcve]

Also make sure you are using PrimeFaces 13.0.8 a few BlockUI items were fixed since 13.0.0
